# Dictionary of lists of functions

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I try to append function objects to list, which is element of dictionary:

```
    jobs = {}
    job = sched.add_date_job(callback, run_at, [params])
    jobs[hereCanBeRandomNumber].append(job)
```

But, it seems I have a problem in last line. Compiler says:`KeyError: 118096950`.

What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the time to visit our [help] to learn about posting a good question.  Particularly, make sure to read about how to write a [mcve].  The code you posted is clearly a snippet, and not minimally complete.  However, in the little bit you did provide, your jobs dictionary is empty.  You can't append to the list you expect at `jobs[hereCanBeRandomNumber]`, since there's nothing that puts that list in the dictionary.

Comment: Assign the value only with `dict[key] = value`, not with the append method, which simply doesn't achieve your wish.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're adding to your dictionary is incorrect.

```
jobs[hereCanBeRandomNumber].append(job)
```

Translates to "Append the job to the value of the dictionary with key `hereCanBeRandomNumber`"

If you're trying to add to the dictionary, use:

```
jobs[hereCanBeRandomNumber] = job
```

This will add to the `jobs` dict, so it looks like:

```
jobs = {118096950: job}
```

Comment: Or `jobs.setdefault(hereCanBeRandomNumber, []).append(job)`.  This will return whatever is in `jobs[hereCanBeRandomNumber]` if there's something there, otherwise return `[]`, which is then an empty list you can append to.  But I don't fully trust that this is the OP's problem - the code they posted is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem here is you are trying to append to a key that does not exist yet.

Take a dictionary like

`jobs = {}`
and doing
`jobs[123].append(foo)`
will produce a KeyError as nothing exists at 123 yet.

To get around this you can do either of the following:

`from collections import defaultdict
jobs = defaultdict(list)
jobs[123].append(foo)`

which means if a key does not exist it is initialised to an empty list first or

`jobs = {}
jobs[123] = jobs.get(123, []).append(job)`

which checks jobs for the presence of the key and if it doesn't exist used an empty list